# How to launch SCORM from offline Mobile App

Tags: windows-phone-8, scorm

We need to know how to launch a SCORM compatible content from a windows8 native app. I have already implemented the same thing in our .net based web application using javascript. Is there a way to launch SCORM content without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The SCORM standard uses JavaScript by definition and wasn't designed with native apps in mind. It is possible to work around SCORM and run SCORM content from a native app and there are products that allow you to do that, e.g. [http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/mobileoffline-scorm/](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/mobileoffline-scorm/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=offline-scorm?pmc=em-1)

You might also like to look at using another standard in place of SCORM. Tin Can API from behind SCORM is designed to replace the SCORM standard and has mobile apps in mind. There's a number of resources about the standard at [http://tincanapi.com/](http://tincanapi.com?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=main?pmc=em-1) including a contact us link that'll get you through to somebody who can answer any follow up questions you have if you don't want to post them publicly here.